# how can i send a header via websocket js and not need a response

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, header

I have js that is making a websocket connection to my go and i need to send a jwt so i have send it in the header but since my websocket is not making a respond chrome is not allowing me to make the request. So i need to either send a respond or set the header in a way that does not need one.

I have tried to wright on my http response in go but it did not work and i can not send it in URL because of security.

client:

```js
if (window["WebSocket"]) {
                conn = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/trip/chat/ws?id={{ trip.id }}", "{{ jwt }}");
                conn.protocol()
                conn.onclose = function (evt) {
                    var item = document.createElement("div");
                    item.innerHTML = "<b>Connection closed.</b>";
                    appendLog(item);
                };
                conn.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    var messages = evt.data.split('\n');
                    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        var item = document.createElement("div");
                        item.innerText = messages[i];
                        appendLog(item);
                    }
                };
```

server:

```golang
func serveWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Yo"))
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    tknstr := r.Header.Get("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol")
    claims := getTokenConntents(tknstr)
    trip, ok := r.URL.Query()["id"]
    if !ok {
        log.Println("Url Param id is missing")
        return
    }
    id, err := strconv.ParseInt(trip[0], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Print("client made")
    if _, ok := Hubs[trip[0]]; !ok {
        hub := newHub()
        go hub.run()
        Hubs[trip[0]] = hub
    }
    if claims.Username != "" && claims.Trip == int(id) {
        client := &Client{hub: Hubs[trip[0]], conn: conn, send: make(chan Message, 256), trip: int(id), claims: claims}
        client.hub.register <- client
        go client.serveLastMessages(int(id))
        go client.writePump()
        go client.readPump()
    } else {
        conn.Close()
    }

}
```

and this is the error that my chrome sends:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/trip/chat/ws?id=7' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: The code `w.Write([]byte("Yo"))` sends an HTTP response with status 200 and body starting with "Yo".  Delete this line of code.  It looks like the client is attempting to send the JWT as a sub-protocol.  Although you can probably make this work with changes to the server code, a better approach is to send the JWT as the first message.

Comment: @CeriseLimón actually i added that line because with out it chrome would say it needs a response.
about sending it as the first message is it really as secure as the header?

Comment: Show the exact error reported by Chrome when when the erroneous `w.Write([]byte("Yo"))` is removed. The error is probably about missing subprotocol in the response.  If so, the server should add a Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header to the handshake response. That said, you should not abuse the protocol header.  What is your security concern regarding message vs. headers?  Do you have infrastructure that logs one and not the other?

Comment: There's a data race on `Hubs`.  Run the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) once you get to the point where the Hubs code is used.

Comment: @CeriseLimón the problem is i can not send a message till the server is connected to client and i serve the history of messages as it connects and my chat hubs are private.

Comment: @CeriseLimón this is the error i get when i do this with out the `w.Write()` 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/trip/chat/ws?id=7' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received

Comment: The error message is telling you that the client requested a subprotocol, but the server did not reply to that request.  Fix by setting the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol handshake response header to  `tknstr`.  This may not work reliably because JWTs are not HTTP header tokens.

Comment: A better approach is to use the first message for authentication. Do not process the first message as a normal message or save the first message to history.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you for your help i will do that.

Comment: If you do use protocol negotiation to transmit the JWT, then you should hex encode the JWT so that it satisfies the HTTP token syntax as described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616.